# URL Processing in Laravel mix doesn't work in postCSS

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have problems with URL Processing in Laravel mix.

here is my app.css

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

/*---------- import LightGallery from node_modules  ----------*/
@import 'lightgallery.js';

/*---------- my styles for thumbnails ----------*/ 
@import 'includes/thumbnails';
```

here is my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .scripts([
          'public/js/app.js',
          'resources/js/includes/script.js'
      ],  'public/js/app.js')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
      require('postcss-import'), 
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('postcss-extend'), 
      require('postcss-nested'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
    ]);
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.6",
        "postcss-extend": "^1.0.5",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-simple-extend": "^1.0.0",
        "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.7",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tkh/tailwind-plugin-flex-basis": "^1.4.0",
        "lightgallery.js": "^1.4.0",
        "npm": "^7.3.0"
    }
}
```

And if I do npm run dev I see following error. It seems that fonts and images from `node_modules/lightgallery.js/dist` don't copied by laravel mix

```
> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 7 errors                               9:06:04 PM

These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/lg.svg?22t19m in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../fonts/lg.ttf?22t19m in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../fonts/lg.woff?22t19m in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../img/loading.gif in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../img/video-play.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../img/vimeo-play.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
* ../img/youtube-play.png in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css
     Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  730 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/lg.svg?22t19m' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/home/http/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:27:15
    at /home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:75:11)
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/lg.svg?22t19m' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1351805-1351838
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/lg.ttf?22t19m' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1351654-1351687
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/lg.woff?22t19m' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1351731-1351765
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/loading.gif' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1368504-1368533
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/video-play.png' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1359119-1359151
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/vimeo-play.png' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1358797-1358829 7:1358953-1358985
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/youtube-play.png' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 7:1359422-1359456 7:1359582-1359616
 @ ./resources/css/app.css
```

But if I do the same job with sass instead postCss everything working.
Here is my working code, but I want to get rid of sass and replace all with postCSS plugins

/resources/css/app.css

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
@import 'includes/thumbnails';
```

/resources/sass/app.scss

```
@import '~lightgallery.js/src/sass/lightgallery';
/* postcss-mixin plugin also doesn't work in my mix file */ 
@import 'mixins/svg';
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .scripts([
          'public/js/app.js',
          'resources/js/includes/script.js'
      ],  'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .styles([
        'resources/css/app.css',
        'public/css/app.css'
      ],'public/css/app.css')
   .postCss('public/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
      require('postcss-import'),
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('postcss-extend'),
      require('postcss-nested'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
    ]);
```

Comment: Where's your package.json?

Comment: just added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in webpack.mix.js, do you need the SASS line? Because it's causing issues.

```
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Ensure the tilde is present to reference the node_modules/ directory in your app.css for lightgallery.js and use the full CSS path.

```
@import '~lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.min.css';
```

Update Node dependencies for Laravel Mix 6, Webpack, Autoprefixer, and PostCSS and update the "scripts" section of package.json to the following.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tkh/tailwind-plugin-flex-basis": "^1.4.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.8.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
        "lightgallery.js": "^1.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "postcss": "^8.2.6",
        "postcss-extend": "^1.0.5",
        "postcss-import": "^8.2.0",
        "postcss-simple-extend": "^1.0.0",
        "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
        "tailwindcss": "2.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^5.23.0"
    }
}
```

Then run `npm update && npm install`.

Now you can run `npm run dev`.

Comment: Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostC            SS version is 8.2.6, but postcss-import uses 7.0.35. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find '~lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.css'
  in [
    /home/http/app/resources/css
  ]

Comment: Once you update everything in the package.json, did you install the updates? via npm update && npm install?

Comment: Yes I did that. Then according to this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/your-current-postcss-version-is-824-but-postcss-import-uses-7035?page=1 I upgraded `postcss-import` to `^14.0.0`. And after `npm run dev` I see error `ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find '~lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.css'
  in [
    /home/http/app/resources/css
  ]
`

Comment: If I delete tilde `@import 'lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.css';` then error is different `ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/lg.ttf?22t19m' in '/home/http/app/resources/css'
    at finishWithoutResolve (/home/http/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/....

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors`

Comment: You are still using the wrong lightgallery URL, look at the post. Copy my package.json... and paste it into your package.json, then run 'npm update && npm install'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228973/discussion-between-karl-hill-and-schel4ok).

Answer (score 6):

Try it in
webpack.mix.js.

install webpack-livereload-plugin with npm

```
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [new LiveReloadPlugin()],
    stats: {
        children: true
    }
});
```

Comment: where we should try?

Comment: in webpack.mix.js in root directory. First You will install webpack-livereload-plugin package. and use it. @Mr.Pyramid